# Access Json file on server side with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a website which displays json data that comes from a localhost. For the moment the json array is in the js server file. However I want it to be an external file.

```
var test = [{
        id: 0,
        test_id: "Password test",
        pass: 1,
        fail: 5,
        time: 0.03,
        pass_fail: 20,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        test_id: "Password test",
        pass: 1,
        fail: 5,
        time: 0.03,
        pass_fail: 20,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        test_id: "Form testing",
        pass: 10,
        fail: 0,
        time: 0.09,
        pass_fail: 100,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        test_id: "Login Test 2",
        pass: 15,
        fail: 0,
        time: 0.04,
        pass_fail: 100,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        test_id: "Pen Test",
        pass: 119,
        fail: 2,
        time: 0.04,
        pass_fail: 0,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        test_id: "Pen Test 2",
        pass: 19,
        fail: 22,
        time: 0.08,
        pass_fail: 1,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        test_id: "Pen Test 3",
        pass: 119,
        fail: 2,
        time: 0.04,
        pass_fail: 40,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        test_id: "Login Test 4",
        pass: 119,
        fail: 2,
        time: 0.04,
        pass_fail: 0,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        test_id: "Pen Test 4",
        pass: 119,
        fail: 210,
        time: 0.04,
        pass_fail: 80,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        test_id: "Pen Test 5",
        pass: 12,
        fail: 2,
        time: 0.04,
        pass_fail: 0,
        comments: [{
            comment: "",
            commentuser: ""
        }, ]
    }
];
```

Here is the get request for the json,

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    console.log(test);
    res.jsonp({
        test: test
    });
});
```

How can I link an external Json file in which the array *test* is present, in the get request ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = require('path/to/external-json/the-file.json');

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    console.log(test);
    res.jsonp({
        test: test
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 ways.

1. `const myJson = require('./myJson.json')`
2. `import myJson from './myJson.json'`
3. `const myJson = await fs.promises.readFile("./myJson.json", "utf-8")`